# Is it better to use heap or stack variables?

Tags: c++, variables, heap-memory, stack-memory

An experienced C++ user told me that I should strive for using heap variables, i.e.:

```
A* obj = new A("A");
```

as opposed to:

```
A obj("A");
```

Aside from all that stuff about using pointers being nice and flexible, he said it's better to put things on the heap rather than the stack (something about the stack being smaller than the heap?). Is it true? If so why?

NB: I know about issues with lifetime. Let's assume I have managed the lifetime of these variables appropriately. (i.e. the only criteria of concern is heap vs. stack storage with no lifetime concern)

Comment: The first code creates a variable on the heap, not the stack. (The pointer is on the stack, but the actual object is not.)

Comment: The `new`'d variable is on the heap; the other is on the stack.  You start off saying your friend recommended stack variables; then you say he said its better to put things on the heap.  This is confusing to us.  Can you clarify which advice you think you were really given?

Comment: The `new`'d _object_ is on the heap (technically has _dynamic storage duration_). It is not a variable as there is no name associated with that object; the only variable declared in `A* obj = new A("A");` is `obj` which is on the stack (technically has _automatic storage duration_) but is a pointer.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say he preferred heap variables. Was a typo.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Depending on the context we can consider heap or stack. Every thread gets a stack and the thread executes instructions by invoking functions. When a function  is called, the function variables are pushed to stack. And when the function returns the stack rollbacks and memory is reclaimed. Now there is a size limitation for the thread local stack, it varies and can be tweaked to some extent. Considering this if every object is created on stack and the object requires large memory, then the stack space will exhaust resulting to stackoverflow error. Besides this if the object is to be accessed by multiple threads then storing such object on stack makes no sense.

Thus small variables, small objects who's size can be determine at compile time and pointers should be stored on stack. The concern of storing objects on heap or free store is, memory management becomes difficult. There are chances of memory leak, which is bad. Also if application tries to access an object which is already deleted, then access violation can happen which can cause application crash.

C++11 introduces smart pointers (shared, unique) to make memory management with heap easier. The actual referenced object is on heap but is encapsulation by the smart pointer which is always on the stack. Hence when the stack rollbacks during function return event or during exception the destructor of smart pointer deletes the actual object on heap. In case of shared pointer the reference count is maintained and the actually object is deleted when the reference count is zero.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer

Comment: Ok, this sounds like what my friend was saying. Let's see what others say. By the way, does C++11 work with visual studio? My concern with using C++11 is that code written with it may have compatibility issues (haven't used C++11 before).

Comment: Yes, VS2010 which is already released has smart pointers you need to include <memory> header. Other features are in VS2011 beta. Here is the link. The new features can be classified into language features and library features. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx

Comment: C++11 spec is now released last year and compilers have started the implementation based on priority. C++11 is "the C++" now. By compatibility issues what exactly you mean? You cannot compile the c++11 code in previous version compiler is that the concern?

Comment: It's mostly code-sharing concerns. Are everyone really going to be using C++11? In python, there appears to be loyalists for both 2.6.5. and 3.0+ and the latter is not backwards compatible.

Comment: This is going to be a issue for another year I believe. But we can always make it clear that the code compiles with so and so version of compiler. It also happened with last release of C++, C++98. Another option is to use boost library smart pointers. The c++11 lib smart pointers are derived from boost lib smart pointers. The better option is to upgrade to latest compiler. How long a project should compile with old version? We often move or are forced to move to latest versions.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give the smart pointers a try. I suppose they'd be kind of like gcnew and make C++ essentially like Java (my mother tongue and which I consider to be a much more elegant language).

Answer (score 10):

There are no general rules regarding use of stack allocated vs heap allocated variables. There are only guidelines, depending on what you are trying to do.

Here are some pros and cons:

Heap Allocation:

Pros:

- more flexible - in case you have a lot of information that is not available at compile-time
- bigger in size - you can allocate more  - however, it's not infinite, so at some point your program might run out of memory if allocations/deallocations are not handled correctly

Cons:

- slower - dynamic allocation is usually slower than stack allocation
- may cause memory fragmentation - allocating and deallocating objects of different sizes will make the memory look like Swiss cheese :) causing some allocations to fail if there is no memory block of the required size available
- harder to maintain - as you know each dynamic allocation must be followed by a deallocation, which should be done by the user - this is error prone as there are a lot of cases where people forget to match every malloc() call with a free() call or new() with delete()

Stack allocation:

Pros:

- faster - which is important mostly on embedded systems (I believe that for embedded there is a MISRA rule which forbids dynamic allocation)
- does not cause memory fragmentation
- makes the behavior of applications more deterministic - e.g. removes the possibility to run out of memory at some point
- less error prone - as the user is not needed to handle deallocation

Cons:

- less flexible - you have to have all information available at compile-time (data size, data structure, etc.)
- smaller in size - however there are ways to calculate total stack size of an application, so running out of stack can be avoided

I think this captures a few of the pros and cons. I'm sure there are more.

In the end it depends on what your application needs.

Answer (score 9):

The **stack should be prefered to the heap**, as **stack allocated variables are automatic variables**: their destruction is done automatically when the program goes out of their context.

In fact, the lifespan of object created on the stack and on the heap is different:

- The local variables of a function or a code block `{}` (not allocated by new), are **on the stack**. They are **automatically destroyed** when you are returning from the function. (their destructors are called and their memory is freed).
- But, if you need something an object to be used outside of the the function, you will have to allocate in on the heap (using new) or return a copy.

Example:

```
 void myFun()
 {
   A onStack; // On the stack
   A* onHeap = new A(); // On the heap
   // Do things...

 } // End of the function onStack is destroyed, but the &onHeap is still alive
```

In this example, `onHeap` will still have its memory allocated when the function ends. Such that if you don't have a pointer to `onHeap` somewhere, you won't be able to delete it and free the memory. It's a memory leak as the memory will be lost until the program end.

However if you were to return a pointer on `onStack`, since `onStack` was destroyed when exiting the function, using the pointer could cause undefined behaviour. While using `onHeap` is still perfectly valid.

To better understand how stack variables are working, you should search information about the **call stack** such as [this article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack). It explains how the variables are stacked to be used in a function.

Answer (score 4):

It is always better to avoid using **new** as much as possible in C++.
However, there are times when you cannot avoid it.
For ex:
Wanting variables to exist beyond their scopes.

So it should be horses for courses really, but if you have a choice always avoid heap allocated variables.

Comment: May be because it sustained by religion, not facts.
You cannot use words like "always" if it is not "always"!

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia: Well here the *always* is **always** and needs to be that way. The answer clearly states *horses for courses* and if **there is a choice**. I don't see where theres room for any non factism.

Comment: Thanks Als, can you comment on Abhijit Kadam's post above?

Comment: @SomeNewbie: I think the answer is fair enough.It explains in detail what i meant by *horses for courses* in my answer. I was too lazy to add that long an answer to be honest.

Comment: That doesn't really address my question though. For all I know, I strongly prefer stack variables for the same reasons as others mentioned, but I suppose what Abhiji Kadam's post brought up is where to draw the line. More precisely, what would be the approximate smallest size of a variable s.t. you'd prefer to put it in the heap instead of the stack?

Comment: @SomeNewbie: There is no drawing the line and precisely, there are no fixed guidelines, you cannot program by a set of specified rules.its micro optimization to do pick stack or heap for performance.Pick one which makes your program intuitive and more easy to write and understand and importantly works correctly.

Comment: Agree, there are no specific guidelines. However it depends on what you are doing with memory like : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219878/stack-overflow-c)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219878/stack-overflow-c

Comment: Alright... I will go with the combination that goes with developmental efficiency. I suppose these things only become important for high performance applications anyway.

Comment: @AbhijitKadam: I fail to understand the purpose of your comment.Was it intended for me?

Comment: @SomeNewbie; Yes. Micro-optimization is harmful.Just write a code that works correctly without bothering of micro-optimization. A code highly optimized but which doesn't work is useless while a correctly working code can always be optimized whenever need arises.

Comment: @Als I mean when one gets stackoverflow exception or think that he can get one on some machine, then he can decide to use "new" over there.

Comment: @AbhijitKadam: Doesn't *"program that works correctly"* cover it? It was already stated in the comment to which you (probably)replied, so i don't know why?

Comment: Yes you are right and I pointed out an example. If inadvertent I have offended you then I apologize.

Comment: @AbhijitKadam: Not offended just I was confused, if your comment was for me or for OP, you probably should have use _@username of OP if it was intended for OP.

Comment: Als,  I've always thought the improvement would be more than that, but now that you mentioned it, my friend is an OCD micro-optimizer who'd go into great details to even micromanage the specifics of how memory is allocated for different variables.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is not as clear cut as some would make you believe.

In general, you should prefer automatic variables (on the stack) because it's just plain easier. However some situations call for dynamic allocations (on the heap):

- unknown size at compile time
- extensible (containers use heap allocation internally)
- large objects

The latter is a bit tricky. In theory, the automatic variables could get allocated infinitely, but computers are finite and worse all, most of the times the size of the stack is finite too (which is an implementation issue).

Personally, I use the following guideline:

- local objects are allocated automatically
- local arrays are deferred to `std::vector<T>` which internally allocates them dynamically

it has served me well (which is just anecdotal evidence, obviously).

*Note: you **can** (and probably should) tie the life of the dynamically allocated object to that of a stack variable using RAII: smart pointers or containers.*

Answer (score 0):

C++ has no mention of the Heap or the Stack. As far as the language is concerned they do not exist/are not separate things.

As for a practical answer - use what works best - do you need fast - do you need guarantees. Application A might be much better with everything on the Heap, App B might fragment OS memory so badly it kills the machine - there is no right answer :-(

Comment: **C++ has no mention of the Heap or the Stack**, that's true. But your compiler is very likely to have a mention of Heap and Stack.

Comment: @olchauvin Totally agree - but if you use my C++ 14882:2011 100% complaint compiler on my AdeProcessor0.1 - can you guarantee where your vars are ;-) - the OP sounds like they are asking for pre-optomization to me

Comment: *100% complaint compiler* ? I've used one or two of those in the past. ;-)

Comment: @PaulR lol - its the one that comp.lang.c++ and comp.lang.c showed me exist. Personally I like a dirty compiler like g++ , if you are nice it will do non standard things. But to be fair the OP is asking about things that are implantation specific. Like SPARC used to core if you did math OPS on ints that were not aligned correctly not matter what you cast them as

Comment: -1 I find answers that obsess on the exact Standard *definitions* (not *guarantees*) to be unhelpful and annoying when the question is only about the practical aspects of something.

Comment: Adrian: *implantation specific* ? You *have* to be using something like OS X 10.7 with autocorrect enabled ?

Comment: I do appreciate Adrian taking the time to respond, but "use what works best" doesn't really say much, because my question is more of "how do you determine what's best?".

Comment: @SomeNewbie what works best is what works best for you. Is it more important to serve a billion request and never miss one or to serve a request in less than 10ms. Maybe we only have 10K ram to work in, maybe the system may never fail. I cannot tell you what works best for you in your situation. Those are your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, don't manage your own memory unless you need to. ;)

Answer (score -4):

Stack = Static Data allocated during compile time. (not dynamic)

Heap = Dyanamic Data allocated during run time. (Very dynamic)

Although pointers are on the Stack...Those pointers are beautiful because they open the doors for dynamic, spontaneous creation of data (depending on how you code your program).

(But I'm just a savage, so why does it matter what i say)