# Why would this cause a Seg. fault, and how can I use GDB to debug it?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, gdb, catch2

The code itself is *extremely* simple. I'm using [Catch2](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2) to unit test, (I really like its interface) and break into `gdb`, but getting no useful information for a Seg. fault thrown by said simple code.

I know exactly *what* is causing the problem, but I don't know *why*, or how I would've gotten the offending line of code from `gdb` (I've extensive usage with the Python equivalent, `pdb`, but errors in Python seem to be a lot more straightforward).

**Flop.hpp**

```
#ifndef FLOP
#define FLOP
class Flop {
     private:
        int tiles_[200][200][200];
     public:
          Flop();
}
#endif
```

**Flop.cpp**

```
#include "Flop.hpp"
Flop::Flop() { }
```

**test_Flop.cpp**

```
#include "catch.hpp"
#include "Flop.hpp"
SCENARIO("I bang my head against a wall") {
    Flop flop;
    WHEN("I try to run this test") {
        THEN("This program SEGFAULTs") {
            REQUIRE(1==1);
        }
    }
}
```

The **main.cpp** contains everything it should, alongside the downloaded **catch.hpp** (as instructed by the tutorial).

I compile this with: `g++ Flop.cpp test_Flop.cpp main.cpp -o run_test` and run it with `gdb -ex run --args ./run_test -b`, which allows Catch2 to break into the debugger. The result is this:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000555555566e9e in ____C_A_T_C_H____T_E_S_T____0() ()
```

With backtrace:

```
#0  0x0000555555566e9e in ____C_A_T_C_H____T_E_S_T____0() ()
#1  0x000055555557e15e in Catch::TestInvokerAsFunction::invoke() const ()
#2  0x000055555557d7b1 in Catch::TestCase::invoke() const ()
#3  0x0000555555577f0a in Catch::RunContext::invokeActiveTestCase() ()
#4  0x0000555555577c59 in Catch::RunContext::runCurrentTest(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&) ()
#5  0x000055555557671b in Catch::RunContext::runTest(Catch::TestCase const&) ()
#6  0x00005555555797cc in Catch::(anonymous namespace)::TestGroup::execute() ()
#7  0x000055555557ab49 in Catch::Session::runInternal() ()
#8  0x000055555557a853 in Catch::Session::run() ()
#9  0x00005555555b6195 in int Catch::Session::run<char>(int, char const* const*) ()
#10 0x000055555558fdf0 in main ()
```

Ok. So, `SIGSEGV` indicates that we tried to read/write to memory that a process does not have access to. If, in **Flop.hpp**, I instead say `int tiles_[10][10][10]`, then everything works fine. So setting `tiles_` to a larger size is somehow reserving a piece of memory that cannot be accessed? I'm new to C++ (and thus new to actually thinking about what's going on in the computer when I program something) so correct me if I'm wrong, but `int tiles_[200][200][200]` shouldn't take much more than 32MB of memory, right?

So with this, I have a couple of questions:

- Why is this causing a Segmentation fault?
- How can I use `gdb` to get me to the offending line of code? The un-simplified version of this code is a few hundred lines total. Luckily, my problem was early on in the class's definition, but commenting everything out and (painstakingly) uncommenting line-by-line still took a while, and this is what `gdb` was meant to prevent!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stack overflow C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219878/stack-overflow-c)

Comment: "_errors in Python seem to be a lot more straightforward_" - Errors in python are decorated by skilled programmers trying to make users (other programmers) aware of underlaying problems encountered.

When you are programming C++, you are often the programmer providing that useful info, so take care of what happens. People rely on you reporting good stuff back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The size of the array

```
int tiles_[200][200][200];
```

is about 30 MB, assuming `sizeof(int) == 4`.

This is larger than typical stack size limits, and so you will write outside the stack space that you are allowed to use when you create an automatic variable of this type with

```
Flop flop;
```

The amount of stack usable by a program is generally limited to a few MB or so, depending on the OS and settings.

`gdb` gives you the location of the segmentation fault: The entry to the test function. Stack space for local variables in a function is allocated usually when the function is entered, so this is where a stack overflow may manifest in a segmentation fault (or depending on how exactly the stack is handled later, when the out-of-bounds stack space is written/read the first time).

Don't save large objects directly as members or with automatic storage duration (i.e. on the stack). Instead allocate large objects dynamically (i.e. on the free store / heap), through a pointer indirection.

The easiest way of doing this is to use `std::vector` instead of built-in arrays. This is also generally preferable over built-in arrays and should be your default choice if you need to store multiple objects of the same type.

In the specific cases where compile-time sized non-allocating arrays are required, `std::array` is superior to built-in arrays as well. In that way you can avoid ever using built-in arrays at all.

Alternatively `std::unique_ptr<...>` allows you to wrap any object type (also built-in arrays) in a dynamically allocated indirection.

Comment: Ah, so, since stack space for local variables is allocated at runtime, `gdb` only knows that whatever was running did something to cause a Seg. fault, and once that Seg. fault was caused, `gdb` itself doesn't really have a way to dig further into what part of some linked function specifically caused it—right? 

If I had contained the whole `Flip` class in a single `.cpp` file, and used `#include Flip.cpp` in `test_Flip.cpp`, would `gdb` then be able to tell me where, in `Flip`, that Seg. fault was caused?

Comment: Yes, when the program sefgaults because it accesses memory that it isn't allowed, the best gdb can do is show you the assembly instruction at which it happened (you can switch to the assembly layout with the `layout` command in gdb) and maybe the source code line if it can be associated, in this case the function head. There is no additional information left in the executable to give you any more information. That is fundamentally different to e.g. Python, but at the same time is the reason that C++ code is generally much faster than Python code, because it doesn't need to add all that stuff.

Comment: @AmagicalFishy The file structure does not play a role and you should *never* include a `.cpp` file in another file. Only header files should be included. The best you can do to get the most detailed information is to separate out as much as possible into individual functions and to then not use optimization options (you didn't in your example compiler command line). Then the stack trace that you will get will show the individual functions. Using optimization flags (such as `-O2`) will cause short functions to be inlined, reverting the above benefit for debugging.

Comment: You should also always compile with the `-g` option if you are debugging your program. This adds additional debugging information in the executable, so gdb can give you more precise information. For release builds you should never use `-g`, but always enable optimizations.

Comment: The reason I asked about `#include Flip.ccp` is not so much because of the file-structure, but because I was wondering if the underlying assembly code is the same. Afaik, when we `#include`, the preprocessor basically copies and pastes whatever is in our included file—so if `gdb` were able to tell me where, in `test_Flip.cpp` the break happened, might it point to exactly where it happened *in the included* `Flip.cpp` file (since it's just copy/pasted into `test_flip.cpp`)? Don't worry, I know not to include the source file, this is just a question born from curiosity.